# How to display tables using xforms:repeat

Tags: css, repeat, css-tables, xforms, xsltforms

I was wondering if anyone knew how to display data using XForms in a table format. I have a code that displays each column tag as rows however, I was wondering how I can display each column tag as columns. I'd like my output to display like this:

1 1 2 

2 3 4

I am a beginner at XForms and have no idea about the basics so if anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
     <head>
  <title>Table with CSS and Divs</title>
  <xf:model><xf:instance>
    <disp xmlns="">
       <row><col>1</col><col>2</col></row>
       <row><col>3</col><col>4</col></row>
    </disp>
  </xf:instance></xf:model>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  /* example of doing layout of a table without using the HTML table tags */

  .table { 
  display:table;
   }

  .tableHeader, .tableRow, .tableFooter, .myRow  {
   display: table-row;
   }

  .leftHeaderCell, .leftCell, .leftFooterCell, 
  .rightHeaderCell, .rightCell, .rightFooterCell,
  .myCell
  {
   display:  table-cell;
   }    
 .myCell {
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border: solid black 2px
   }
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="table">

        <xf:repeat nodeset="row" id="idrow"> 
        <div class="myRow">  
            <div class="myCell"><xf:output ref="position()"/></div> 
                <xf:repeat nodeset="col" id="idcol">    
            <div class="myCell"><xf:output ref="."/></div>

             </xf:repeat>
        </div>
        </xf:repeat> 
    </div>
         </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: I am running your code, and see that it indeed shows "1 1 2" on the first line, and "2 3 4" on the second. But I am not sure understand the question; what would you like it to display instead?

Answer (score 0):

XSLTForms substitutes XForms elements into HTML elements (have a look with a debugger to check this). Adding DIV elements is a problem with nested repeats.

This has been fixed for the TABLE/TR/TD structure because it can easily be detected by XSLTForms. DIV elements with table-* CSS properties are not in the same situation...

Here is an example working with XSLTForms:

```
    <body>
    <table>
        <xf:repeat nodeset="row" id="idrow"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xf:output value="position()"/>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <xf:repeat nodeset="col" id="idcol">    
                                <td>
                                    <xf:output ref="."/>
                                </td>
                            </xf:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xf:repeat> 
    </table>
</body>
```

-Alain

Comment: Hi Alain,    I tried using the table format and for some reason, it's still not working. is there anyway you could show me an example? i looked at the ones online and they were all kind of complicated. Also, I am using eXist-DB to serve the code and for somereason, the <table xf:repeat-nodeset> is not compatible with it, is there an alternat solution? here is the code i have so far and its still not giving me the correct output.  <xf:repeat nodeset="/disp/row">
  <table border = "1">
  <tr>
   <td><xf:output ref="col"/></td>   
 <td><xf:output ref="position()"/></td>     
  </tr>

Comment: Hi, I tried it your example and for some reason the only output I am getting is 1 2 in separate rows. 
I'm not getting the values of the column at all, I think it only outputs the position of the rows. Also, I am not getting it in tabular format. There's no borders or anything.

Comment: By the way, I am using IE v.8 as my browser. I noticed that some of it works in mozilla but not on IE. would this change my code? Also i figured that i am not able to repeat the <td> tag and thats the one that produces the columns. does you have a clue why?